# Getting a different value after adding and subtracting a binary number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have problem in my code where I'm first encoding a string into binary, adding a binary number to the result, then subtracting again the same binary number. But I'm getting a different value than the initial one.

I'm converting a string into binary number using this code:

```
name = "hani123"
```

but unfortunately I'm getting different result: **name= hani125**. Could please take look into my code and find out where my problem is. I'm using spyder software python 3.6. Thanks!

Comment: The code in the subtraction is confusing, you're mixing negative `r` with positive `carry`, and you comparison is on `r` and positive values. You should refactorize this part, chances are the error is coming from there.

Comment: could you please try help me in that part of subtraction binary, because its not give me error there give, just give me different answer

Comment: Try to see the subtraction as an addition of 2's complement. Here you process x and y bits similarly, which is not possible for a subtraction (your carry should not behave the same if you do `1 - 0` and if you do `0 - 1`). So normally, you invert `y`, add 1 (or use the carry), then you do an addition.

Comment: could you explain more, i didnt understand, try change my code sir to be clear. thanks

Comment: Is this a homework where you need to write the decoder?

Comment: Subtracting `b010 - b001` is the same as adding `b010 + (b110 + b001)` (without the extra MSB due to the carry, so only keep 3 digits for the result), it's how subtraction is made in binary. If you don't / can't do that, check the part of your code in the subtraction, it's not logical to have `r -= 0 if x[i] == '0' else 1` and `r -= 0 if y[i] == '0' else 1`, because it's a subtraction so x and y behave differently. I'm just giving you hints, I won't give you the answer :)

Comment: of course not homework, i have problem in my code thats why i share it to find out whats wrong in my code, i had try different way to fix and its not working, so kindly if you can find the problem u can fix it. thanks

Comment: sir i know the subtraction method, and different from addition, but i had try ur way not working, if you can't share your answer it's your wish. thanks for your help

Comment: All right, have a peek below, that should give an idea without using the 2's complement, since I understand that's not what you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the subtracting method without using 2's complement:

```
def sub_binary_nums(x,y):
    max_len = max(len(x), len(y))

    x = x.zfill(max_len)
    y = y.zfill(max_len)

    result = ''
    carry = 0

    for i in range(max_len-1, -1, -1):
        r = 1 if x[i] == '1' else 0
        r -= 1 if y[i] == '1' else 0
        r -= carry
        result = ('1' if r % 2 == 1 else '0') + result
        carry = 1 if r < 0 else 0

    if carry !=0 : result = '1' + result

    return result
```

Note that in the original code, you process `x` and `y` in the same way, like the addition, but this is not logical: `X` "goes up" while `y` "goes down". I rewrote that part to show how we human process the subtraction.

You didn't need to resize the result, so I removed that as well.

In the case of a negative value, your result will have one extra MSB bit at '1', I'm not sure you want that?

```
> sub_binary_nums('000', '001')
> '1111'
```

If that is not the case, simply comment out this line:

```
    # not necessary: if carry !=0 : result = '1' + result
```

Finally, we rarely use indices in Python. For example, you can change the loop like this (check out the `zip` and `reversed` functions), this is less costly to execute. But I suppose the point of your exercice is to examine the addition/subtraction, not to program in Python.

```
def sub_binary_nums(x,y):
    max_len = max(len(x), len(y))

    x = x.zfill(max_len)
    y = y.zfill(max_len)

    result = ''
    carry = 0

    for xbit, ybit in zip(reversed(x), reversed(y)):
        r = 1 if xbit == '1' else 0
        r -= 1 if ybit == '1' else 0
        r -= carry
        result = ('1' if r % 2 == 1 else '0') + result
        carry = 1 if r < 0 else 0

    #if carry !=0 : result = '1' + result

    return result
```